Polars: Use column values to reference other column in when / then expression
I have a Polars dataframe where I'd like to derive a new column using a when/then expression. The values of the new column should be taken from a different column in the same dataframe. However, the column from which to take the values differs from row to row.
Here's a simple example:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "frequency": [0.5, None, None, None],
        "frequency_ref": ["a", "z", "a", "a"],
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "z": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    }
)

The resulting dataframe should look like this:
res = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "frequency": [0.5, None, None, None],
        "frequency_ref": ["a", "z", "a", "a"],
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "z": [5, 6, 7, 8],
        "res": [0.5, 6, 3, 4]
    }
)

I tried to create a dynamic reference using a nested pl.col:
# Case 1) Fixed value is given
fixed_freq_condition = pl.col("frequency").is_not_null() & pl.col("frequency").is_not_nan()
# Case 2) Reference to distribution data is given
ref_freq_condition = pl.col("frequency_ref").is_not_null()

# Apply the conditions to calculate res
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(fixed_freq_condition)
    .then(pl.col("frequency"))
    .when(ref_freq_condition)
    .then(
      pl.col(pl.col("frequency_ref"))
    )
    .otherwise(0.0)
    .alias("res"),
)

Which fails with  TypeError: invalid input for "col". Expected "str" or "DataType", got 'Expr'.
What works (but only as an intermediate solution) is by explicitly listing every possible column value in a very long when/then expression. This is far from optimal as the column names might change in the future and produces a lot of code repititon.
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(fixed_freq_condition)
    .then(pl.col("frequency"))
    .when(pl.col("frequency_ref") == "a")
    .then(pl.col("a"))
    # ... more entries
    .when(pl.col("frequency_ref") == "z")
    .then(pl.col("z"))
    .otherwise(0.0)
    .alias("res"),
)


Your df does not match up with the "same" columns in res.

Thanks for the hint! Should be fixed now

You could build the when/then in a loop:
freq_refs = df.get_column("frequency_ref")
expr = pl.when(False).then(None)  # dummy starter value
for c in freq_refs:
    expr = expr.when(pl.col("frequency_ref") == c).then(pl.col(c))
expr = expr.otherwise(0)


# Apply the conditions to calculate res
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(fixed_freq_condition)
    .then(pl.col("frequency"))
    .when(ref_freq_condition)
    .then(expr)
    .otherwise(0.0)
    .alias("res"),
)

df

shape: (4, 5)
┌───────────┬───────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ frequency ┆ frequency_ref ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ res │
│ ---       ┆ ---           ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64       ┆ str           ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1         ┆ a             ┆ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1.0 │
│ null      ┆ b             ┆ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 6.0 │
│ null      ┆ a             ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 3.0 │
│ null      ┆ a             ┆ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ 4.0 │
└───────────┴───────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


Thanks a lot for your answer, this is the most performant approach so far! I didn't know expression could be chained like this in a loop, this is very helpful.

Exploring two options:
Option 1 (pl.coalesce)
You could use pl.coalesce, keeping the first non-null value.
df = (
    df.with_columns(
        pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(
                (pl.col("frequency").is_not_null()) 
                | (pl.col("frequency_ref") == col))
            .then(pl.col(f"{col}")) 
            for col in [c for c in df.columns if c != "frequency_ref"]
        )
        .alias('res')
    )
)

Output
┌───────────┬───────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ frequency ┆ frequency_ref ┆ a   ┆ z   ┆ res │
│ ---       ┆ ---           ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64       ┆ str           ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.5       ┆ a             ┆ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 0.5 │
│ null      ┆ z             ┆ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 6.0 │
│ null      ┆ a             ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 3.0 │
│ null      ┆ a             ┆ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ 4.0 │
└───────────┴───────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

Input used
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "frequency": [0.5, None, None, None],
        "frequency_ref": ["a", "z", "a", "a"],
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "z": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    }
)

(OP's df does not match up with the "same" columns in res.)

Option 2 (.unpivot + .group_by and pl.concat)
pl.concat([
    df,
    (
        df.with_row_index()
        .unpivot(index=['frequency_ref', 'index'], value_name='res')
        .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
        .agg(
            pl.when((pl.col('variable') == 'frequency') 
                    | (pl.col('frequency_ref') == pl.col('variable')))
            .then(pl.col('res'))
            .drop_nulls()
            .first()
        )
        .select('res')
    )
    ], how='horizontal')

# same output

Explanation

Add an index with pl.DataFrame.with_row_index and add it to 'frequency_ref' as index inside .unpivot, while setting value_name to 'res'.
now, apply .group_by on 'index' with maintain_order=True and inside group_by.agg use pl.when to get res for pl.col('variable') == 'frequency' or the match with 'frequency_ref', adding pl.DataFrame.drop_nulls before getting group_by.first.
Finally, select 'res' (pl.DataFrame.select) and join to the original df via pl.concat.


If you .melt(['frequency', 'frequency_ref', 'index']) I think you can do when(freq.is_not_null).then(freq).when(freq_ref = var).then(value).drop_nulls().first().over(index) and then unique by index. Still a bit wordy - but gets rid of the groupby/agg/join/drop.

Or maybe .melt(..).group_by("index", maintain_order=True).agg(when.then().drop_nulls().first()) would be even less verbose.

@jqurious: updated accordingly (hopefully not misrepresenting your suggestion). Excellent pointers, thank you very much!

Thanks a lot for your answers! I tried both approaches, but unfortunately they both run out of memory on my machine (original df has > 15 mio rows)

One can concatenate the columns you want to obtain data from into a list
and then .list.get the desired value. If you embed this approach into a
pl.coalesce to obtain you end up with the desired result.
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "frequency": [.5, None, None, None, None],
    "frequency_ref": ["a", "b", "a", "c", "z"],
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "b": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "c": [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    "z": [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
})

nonfreq_idx = {
    c: i for i, c in enumerate(
        (c for c in df.columns if not c.startswith('frequency'))
    )
}

print(
    df
    .with_columns(
        res=(
            pl.coalesce(
                col('frequency'),
                pl.concat_list(nonfreq_idx).list.get(
                    col('frequency_ref').replace_strict(nonfreq_idx, return_dtype=pl.Int32)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    # shape: (5, 7)
    # ┌───────────┬───────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
    # │ frequency ┆ frequency_ref ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ z   ┆ res  │
    # │ ---       ┆ ---           ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
    # │ f64       ┆ str           ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64  │
    # ╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
    # │ 0.5       ┆ a             ┆ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 10  ┆ 20  ┆ 0.5  │
    # │ null      ┆ b             ┆ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 11  ┆ 21  ┆ 6.0  │
    # │ null      ┆ a             ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 12  ┆ 22  ┆ 3.0  │
    # │ null      ┆ c             ┆ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ 13  ┆ 23  ┆ 13.0 │
    # │ null      ┆ z             ┆ 5   ┆ 9   ┆ 14  ┆ 24  ┆ 24.0 │
    # └───────────┴───────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
)


Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately, this approach runs out of memory on my machine when applied to the original df with more than 15 mio rows.
